# Switching out an object's prototype

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand how prototypes work. Why does the following break?

```
var A = function A(){this.a = 0},
    aa = new A;

A.prototype = {hi:"hello"};

aa.constructor.prototype //->{hi:"hello"} ok so far :)

aa.hi //undefined?? why? :(
```

Comment: woops, made a correction to aa.hi

Comment: Removed salutation: "Thanks in advance!", don't do it next time

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you meant in the last line `aa.hi` instead of `aa.hello`.

It gives you `undefined` because the `A.prototype` is assigned **after** the new object (`aa`) has been already created.

In your second line:

```
//...
aa = new A;
//...
```

This will create an object that inherits from `A.prototype`, at this moment, `A.prototype` is a simple empty object, that inherits from `Object.prototype`.

This object will remain referenced by the internal `[[Prototype]]` property of the `aa` object instance.

Changing `A.prototype` after this, will not change the direct inheritance relationship between `aa` and that object.

In fact, there is no standard way to change the `[[Prototype]]` internal property, some implementations give you access through a non-standard property called `__proto__`.

To get the expected results, try:

```
var A = function A () { this.a = 0 };
A.prototype = { hi:"hello" };

var aa = new A;

aa.hi; // "hello"
```

Comment: +1 - Might be worth adding that if the OP had added a property to the prototype as opposed to assigning a new object to it, `aa.hi` would return `"hello"`.

Comment: Thanks! i did not know about the internal [[Prototype]]. Is there such a thing as an internal constructor too?